# MaterialAlertDialogBuilder crashes

Tags: android, kotlin

I have very simple `MaterialAlertDialog`. When i call the  `showDialog()` function from activity, it shows dialog. But It is only works one time. When I call `showDialog()` second time(after the dismiss dialog). it crashes.

```
class EditProductNameDialog(
    activity: Activity
) {

    private var isShowing = false
    private var dialog: Dialog? = null
    private var materialAlertDialogBuilder: MaterialAlertDialogBuilder
    private var buttonOk: TextView
    private var buttonCancel: Button

    init {
        materialAlertDialogBuilder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(activity)
        val customAlertDialogView = LayoutInflater.from(activity)
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_edit_product_name_dialog, null, false)

        buttonOk = customAlertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOK)
        buttonCancel = customAlertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel)

        materialAlertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
        materialAlertDialogBuilder.setView(customAlertDialogView)
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun showDialog(
        productName: String,
        onCancelClicked: (() -> Unit),
        onOKClicked: (() -> Unit)
    ) {
        if (!isShowing) {
            isShowing = true
            buttonCancel.setOnClickListener {
                onCancelClicked()
                dismissDialog()
            }
            buttonOk.setOnClickListener {
                //onOKClicked()
                dismissDialog()
            }
            dialog = materialAlertDialogBuilder.show()
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun dismissDialog() {
        if (isShowing) {
            isShowing = false
            dialog?.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### Error:

```
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.x, PID: 22834
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5330)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5153)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5122)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController.setupCustomContent(AlertController.java:657)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:475)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:233)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:279)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:453)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:334)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1009)
at com.x.presentation.home.EditProductNameDialog.showDialog(EditProductNameDialog.kt:51)
at com.x.presentation.home.HomeFragment$onCreateView$2.onUpdateDeviceNameClicked(HomeFragment.kt:108)
at com.x.presentation.home.HomeAdapter$ViewHolder.bind$lambda$3(HomeAdapter.kt:117)
at com.x.presentation.home.HomeAdapter$ViewHolder.$r8$lambda$aTtDIYUkGHPBeMRj7HGd0tdAPJI(Unknown Source:0)
at com.x.presentation.home.HomeAdapter$ViewHolder$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7751)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7724)
at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:858)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8280)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
```

Comment: Can you provide a code for how you using dialog in Fragment or Adapter?